# Pandas .equals method returns different results between windows and linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, windows

I am trying to deploy the same code on **windows10** using **conda**, and the unit tests that work on **linux** does not function on **windows**.

**On Ubuntu:**

**df_1**

```py
                    col_1                 col_2                      col_3
0                     [-]                     1                        nul
1                     [-]                     1                    pas top
2         [+, plus_small]                     2  personal-minute du centre
3         [+, plus_small]                     2                        top
4         [+, plus_small]                     2                  tres bien
```

when we take a look at the details

**df_1.to_dict()**

```py
{
 'col_1': {0: ['-'], 1: ['-'], 2: ['+', 'plus_small'], 3: ['+', 'plus_small'], 4: ['+', 'plus_small']}, 
 'col_2': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2}, 
 'col_3': {0: 'nul', 1: 'pas top', 2: 'personal-minute du centre', 3: 'top', 4: 'tres bien'}
}
```

when we take a look at the details

**df_2**

```py
                    col_1                 col_2                      col_3
0                     [-]                     1                        nul
1                     [-]                     1                    pas top
2         [+, plus_small]                     2  personal-minute du centre
3         [+, plus_small]                     2                        top
4         [+, plus_small]                     2                  tres bien
```

**df_2.to_dict()**

```py
{
 'col_1': {0: ['-'], 1: ['-'], 2: ['+', 'plus_small'], 3: ['+', 'plus_small'], 4: ['+', 'plus_small']}, 
 'col_2': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2}, 
 'col_3': {0: 'nul', 1: 'pas top', 2: 'personal-minute du centre', 3: 'top', 4: 'tres bien'}
}
```

**Result**

```py
df_1.equals(df_2)                                                                                                                                                                                     
True
```

**On Windows10:**

**df_1**

```py
                    col_1                 col_2                      col_3
0                     [-]                     1                        nul
1                     [-]                     1                    pas top
2         [+, plus_small]                     2  personal-minute du centre
3         [+, plus_small]                     2                        top
4         [+, plus_small]                     2                  tres bien
```

when we take a look at the details

```py
{
 'col_1': {0: ['-'], 1: ['-'], 2: ['+', 'plus_small'], 3: ['+', 'plus_small'], 4: ['+', 'plus_small']}, 
 'col_2': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2}, 
 'col_3': {0: 'nul', 1: 'pas top', 2: 'personal-minute du centre', 3: 'top', 4: 'tres bien'}
}
```

**df_2**

```py
                    col_1                 col_2                      col_3
0                     [-]                     1                        nul
1                     [-]                     1                    pas top
2         [+, plus_small]                     2  personal-minute du centre
3         [+, plus_small]                     2                        top
4         [+, plus_small]                     2                  tres bien
```

when we take a look at the details

**df2.to_dict()**

```py
{
 'col_1': {0: ['-'], 1: ['-'], 2: ['+', 'plus_small'], 3: ['+', 'plus_small'], 4: ['+', 'plus_small']}, 
 'col_2': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2}, 
 'col_3': {0: 'nul', 1: 'pas top', 2: 'personal-minute du centre', 3: 'top', 4: 'tres bien'}
}
```

```py
df_1 == df_2
                    col_1                 col_2                      col_3
0                    True                  True                       True
1                    True                  True                       True
2                    True                  True                       True
3                    True                  True                       True
4                    True                  True                       True
```

and then :

```py
df_1.equals(df_2)
False
```

Comment: Can you post `df1.to_dict()` and `df2.to_dict()` to question? It would be easy to reproduce in our machines, rather than use `pd.read_clipboard`

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Windows 10, python3.7.4 pandas1.0.3 numpy 1.18.3 When I ran `df_1.equals(df_2)` is `True`

Comment: When I copy paste back into windows, It works for me too. I will just swap the equals for an equality between the dicts thank you @Ch3steR !!

Comment: `df.equals` returns `False` if `dtypes` don't match that may be a reason not sure. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can replace the **.equals** method by a **to_dict==**

Before:

```py
df_1.equals(df_2)
False
```

After:

```py
df_1.to_dict() == df_2.to_dict()
True
```

Thank you @Ch3steR for the idea!